# Show all rows from a joined table by date

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, join

Good day

I've been struggling trying to make a query... maybe it is impossible to do it in a simple query... maybe not... that's why after several days I come to your help.

I have 7 joined tables, but for simplicity, let's say they are only 2

```
TblDeffects
------
Date          IdOperation    Deffects
2013-12-12         1             1
2013-12-12         2             1
2013-12-11         1             1
2013-12-11         3             1
2013-11-10         1             1
2013-11-09         5             1

TblOperations
------
Id    Description
1     Operation 1
2     Operation 2
3     Operation 3
4     Operation 4
5     Operation 5
```

Now, supposing that Deffects lists is longer I want to join both tables, separating them by week (starting on friday and ending on thursday)
I can do that... I think...
But I also want to get ALL operations from the Operations table for each day...
so I could get something like

```
Output
------
StartDate          IdOperation    Deffects    Description
2013-12-06            1             2         Operation 1
2013-12-06            2             1         Operation 2
2013-12-06            3             1         Operation 3
2013-12-06            4             0         Operation 4 <- No deffects for this
2013-12-06            5             0         Operation 5 <- No deffects for this

2013-11-08            1             1         Operation 1
2013-11-08            2             0         Operation 2 <- No deffects for this
2013-11-08            3             0         Operation 3 <- No deffects for this
2013-11-08            4             0         Operation 4 <- No deffects for this
2013-11-08            5             1         Operation 5
```

And if possible to get the missing weeks with a 0 in the deffects column...
(The empty row is just to separate the months and make it a little easier to read here)

Right now what I get are both joined tables and at the end the operation that wasn't included (in this case Operation #4 with a NULL date)

Is it possible to create a query like that??

Thank you

Comment: can you please set up a sqlfiddle with a working set of data?

Comment: hi @BeNdErR, here is a sqlfiddle demonstrating what I mean http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3142db/1 , as you can see, there are 2 result sets, the first one is what I can get... but the second is as I want to get it, the difference is that for each week ALL operations are included (with 0 defects), and also the missing weeks (where no defects were captured) are included, is it possible???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to depend on the Deffects table being populated with data, you need a temporary table containing the dates you want to check. The only way to get this, is a loop unfortunately.

```
DECLARE @dates TABLE(Date DATETIME NOT NULL UNIQUE)
DECLARE @firstDate DATETIME = '2013-11-08T00:00:00Z'
DECLARE @weeks INT = 7
DECLARE @currentWeek INT = 0
WHILE (@currentWeek < @weeks) BEGIN
  INSERT @dates VALUES (DATEADD(DAY, @currentWeek * 7, @firstDate))
  SET @currentWeek = @currentWeek + 1
END

SELECT Dates.Date, Operations.Id IdOperation, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Defects WHERE Defects.date_inspected >= Dates.Date AND Defects.date_inspected < DATEADD(DAY, 7, Dates.Date) AND Defects.id_operation = Operations.Id) AS Deffects, Operations.Description
  FROM @dates Dates
  CROSS JOIN Operations
  ORDER BY Dates.Date DESC
```

SqlFiddle for this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3142db/25

EDIT: Adjusted code to match the sqlFiddle provided.

Comment: Hi Andreas, I think I got a little confused while trying to explain, here is a sqlfiddle that I set up demonstrating what I want to achieve... do you think it is possible?

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer to match your fiddle. It does now return exactly the values expected.

Comment: Awesome! thanks a lot!!! just one quick question... I forgot that each operation is linked to a process and each process to a product... so I there are many more operations in the Operations table that I don't want to see... when doing the cross join I do a subquery... is there a better way??? (I updated the sqlfiddle) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7776f/1 , anyway, thanks a lot, it was really helpful, never thought of doing it that way or CROSS JOIN

Comment: Yep, that looks alright. If you want to avoid the subquery, you could also use an INNER JOIN after the CROSS JOIN: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7776f/4. The execution plan is unaffected by the change and the query looks a little simpler IMO.